# Internet issue in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ethernet

I am using ubuntu 16.04 ..in which
Ethernet wired internet is not working

When i did
 *sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/backup.resolv.conf*

Then wifi internet works but ethernet gives firefox error as
*Server not found*

Comment: not a solution, but try to install `16.04.2` instead of using `16.04`. I faced a lot of network issues in `16.04`, but these were fixed in `16.04.1+` versions

Comment: But i have lot of data in ubuntu...

Comment: i see, so thats not an option. If you can, try booting from an `16.04.2` live cd (or usb), and see if the ethernet works there. If it does, we then can be sure it's the issue of your current os, not your hardware.

Comment: How to install ubuntu without affecting data??

Comment: I am guessing your ethernet works properly on live cd?
Reinstalling ubuntu without data loss depends on your disk structure. You can see the answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=reinstall+ubuntu)

Comment: If you can connect to a different source of internet (via wifi, tether mobile data) for some time, you can just run the update command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt full-upgrade  && sudo apt dist-upgrade `

Comment: Yes i can connect with wifi. But interminal after putting command said by you... Then it says could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock open 11 resoirce temporarily unavailable unable to lock the administration directory  var /lib/dpkg is another process using it??

Comment: Yes, it seems another update/install is running, if you can't find which process, just reboot and try

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'edit connection' delete that particular connection. Restart the modem and connect again. Make sure you have the up to date drivers and OS.

Comment: No still not working

Comment: what type of wired connection? ethernet cable or usb. because some drivers for usb modems are still missing.

Comment: Usb with usb tethering actually before 10 days it was working correctly but latter not